# есть 2 таблицы. 1-я: типы транспорта. 2-я характеристики по id типов

Tags: javascript, c#, mysql

Нужно при добавлении нового транспорта значению value в select'е вывести новые характеристики в виде input'ов именно того вида транспорта id которого равен value выбранного значения в select'e

```
<label>Введите название транспорта</label><input name="name">
        <label>Категория</label></td>
            <script>
                function update(e, targetId) {
                    let target = document.getElementById(targetId);
                    let ob = e.options[e.selectedIndex]
                    target.value = `${ob.text}`
                }</script>


            <select name="type" onchange="update(event.target, 'b1')">
                <option value='' selected>Выберите категорию</option>
                @foreach (var wag in ViewBag.listTypes)
                {
                    <option value="@types.Id">@types.Name</option>
                }
            </select>
<button type="submit" value="">Add</button>
```

... и тут дальше появляются input'ы по idType = @types.Id. Нужен скрипт или запрос не знаю как правильно